# Sunspot Rails to order search results by model id?

Tags: sunspot, sunspot-rails

Assume that I have the following model and I have made it searchable with `sunspot_rails`.

```
class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
  end
end
```

Standard `schema.xml` of Sunspot in Rails declare `id` as an indexed field. When I use the web interface to access solr and test queries a query like:

```
http://localhost:8982/solr/select/?q=id%3A%22Case+15%22&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on
```

which searches for `Cases` with `id` equal to `Case 15` works fine and returns results.

The problem is when I carry out the search with Sunspot Rails in the rails console:

```
s = Case.search do 
    keywords('id:"Case 15"')
end
```

I get:

```
=> <Sunspot::Search:{:fl=>"* score", :rows=>10, :start=>0, :q="id:\"Case 15\"", :defType=>"dismax", :fq=>["type:Case"]}>
```

which show that it correctly puts in `:q` the correct query value, but the hits are 0:

```
s.hits
```

returns

```
=> []
```

If we assume that `keywords` is not equivalent and only searches the `text` field (full-text search) and not the field defined before the colon `:`, then I can try the following:

```
s = Case.search do
  with(:id, "Case 15")
end
```

but this fails with a Sunspot exception:

```
Sunspot::UnrecognizedFieldError: No field configured for Case with name 'id'
```

How can I search using the indexed standard solr/sunspot `id` field of my model?

And to make the question more useful, how can I order by the id. The following does not work:

```
s = Case.search do
  keywords("xxxx")
  order_by :id, :desc
end
```

does not work. `Sunspot::UnrecognizedFieldError: No field configured for Case with name 'id'`

Answer (score 4):

The id that you are talking about is a Sunspot internal field and it should not be used directly.

Why not add your own id field (change variable name, to avoid name collision):

```
class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    integer :model_id {|content| content.id }
  end
end
```

and then

```
s = Case.search do
  keywords("xxxx")
  order_by :model_id, :desc
end
```

Other (messy) option would be to hack directly [solr params](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#sort):

```
s = Case.search do
  keywords("xxxx")
  adjust_solr_params(:sort, 'id desc')
end
```

Comment: Since it has been a long time since I have posted this question, meanwhile, I have implemented a workaround, which resembles to your first suggestion about adding my own id field. But it was `id` that I added as follows: `class Case < ActiveRecord::Base searchable do integer :id end end` which is a workaround, since it creates another indexable field "id_i". Somebody has to tell me why, if not, or how, if yes, I can use the original id to order by.

Comment: Both your questions are answered in my response :) 1. Why not: because it's an internal field used by Sunspot, so you should not use it or make assumptions about it, as it would break the encapsulation principle (also, with a new version of sunspot, its meaning or its implementation can completely change) 2. If you really want to use it, look at the last part of my answer.

Comment: I certainly found your post useful.